# Persisting Side Menu Drawer and AppBar in Flutter Web with GetX and Handling Browser Back/Forward Buttons

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-getx, flutter-web-browser

I'm currently working on a Flutter web project using the GetX state management library. I have implemented a side menu drawer and an app bar in my application. However, I'm facing an issue with persistence – I want both the side menu drawer and app bar to remain consistent across different pages, and I also need to handle browser back and forward buttons seamlessly.

Here are the key aspects I'm struggling with:

Persistence of Side Menu Drawer and App Bar:
I want the side menu drawer and app bar to persist across different pages in my Flutter web application. Currently, they reload with each new page, causing a less-than-ideal user experience. How can I ensure that the side menu drawer and app bar remain consistent throughout the user's navigation?

Handling Browser Back and Forward Buttons:
I also need to address the issue of browser navigation. When a user clicks the browser's back or forward button, the application should respond appropriately, maintaining the state of the side menu drawer and app bar. How can I achieve this with the GetX library in a Flutter web application?

**I've gone through multiple answers on forums and Q&A sites, but unfortunately, none of them have provided a suitable resolution for my specific scenario.**

I appreciate any guidance or code snippets that can help me resolve these issues and improve the overall user experience of my Flutter web application.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!